# OOP and WordPress shortcode

Tags: shortcode, oop

I tried to add a shortcode this way

```
class MyPlugin {

    function __construct() {
        $this->make_shortcode();
    }

    function ShowMsg($cls, $lst4) {
        $data = shortcode_atts(array('phn' => '', 'msg' => ''), $atts);
        return 'You sent '.$data['msg '] .' from '.$data['phn'] ;
    }

    function make_shortcode() {
        add_shortcode('ShowMsg', 'ShowMsg');
    }

}
new MyPlugin;
```

And `[ShowMsg phn="123456" msg="Test Message"]` isn't working, it's returning full shortcode instead of desired text.

I need your advice to fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not the way you add an object method as a callback.

```
function make_shortcode() {
    add_shortcode('ShowMsg', array($this,'ShowMsg'));
}
```

This is explained [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_add_action_with_a_class) as it pertains to actions and filters, but the principle is the same.

I should add that anonymous classes make for painful debugging. Instantiate that class to a variable. It will save you headaches.

Comment: Agreed. How Wordpress instantiates class in this regard has a few eccentricities that can cause headaches. Better to use a wrapper function to instantiate the class and be done with it.